# Gmail API Returns 404 for a MessageId

Tags: php, gmail-api

So this is my process flow for sending a new email.

I send `draftId` from front end Gmail to back-end server, and then from `draftId`, I get `messageId`.

When I try to later get info on that `messageId`, the Gmail API Service returns:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

I was able to research and look into message history API to see that for some reason, that sent message is marked as deletedMessages.

However, the message shows as in my Sent emails so it is clearly not deleted.

This appears to have started showing up recently as well.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the flow you are doing. What do you mean with "I send a draftId"?

Comment: @Jescanellas Using Inbox SDK, we send draftId of email message that is being sent to the back-end. Then from that draftId we get messageId. It seems like sometimes it works sometimes it does not as it shows message as deleted even though it is not.

Comment: That's odd, I made some tests and I couldn't reproduce the issue. I recommend you to file a bug on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=823912) if you have the steps to reproduce it (screenshots and videos are welcome), or [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) if you think it might be related to your account (if you are G Suite).